# mongodb - How can I group documents with duplicates and sort their numbers to an array without duplicates?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate

Here is my sample data:

```
[
  { name: "bob",number:20 },
  { name: "bob",number:10 }, 
  { name: "kol",number:20 },
  { name: "bob",number:20 }
  { name: "kol",number:10 },
  { name: "kol",number:10 }
]
```

I want to get a document per name with an array of unique numbers sorted.
expected output:

```
    [
      {
        name:"bob",
        number: [10,20] // with sort, not 20,10
      },
      {
        name:"kol",
        number: [10,20]
      }
    ]
```

I tried something like this but not working as I want. I did not get the array of numbers sorted.

```
user.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$name',
                name: { $first: '$name' },
                number: {$addToSet: '$number'}
            }
        },
        {$sort: {name: 1}}
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `$sort` before you `$group` by the name and use `$push` in order to keep all numbers, instead of `$addToSet`. For keeping the numbers a set just use `$setIntersection` to remove duplicates:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$sort: {number: 1}},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      number: {$push: "$number"}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: "$_id",
      number: {$setIntersection: ["$number"]},
      _id: 0
    }
  },
{$sort: {name: 1}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T0mhcxWacCZ)

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I forgot to add in the question. i want unique data and in the database, there can be duplicate data. let me update this question.

Comment: Please check out the updated answer

Comment: --hi, still some sort issue.
check this https://mongoplayground.net/p/bYTTk40930o

Comment: it give sometime kol first and sometime bob first

Comment: That's because we only sorted the inner array. Updated now